# debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Tags: server, amazon-ec2, aws

I am trying to connect AWS EC2 which is launch with .pem key, But when I am trying to connect it using pem it is asking for ubuntu user which is a EC2 user from AWS. Previously I was able to login with the same key. Now it is asking for password

Comment: It's telling you that it's NOT able to use `publickey`. Read 'man ssh-copy-id`, edit your post and give details about "connect it using. pem".

Comment: I tried that too, but it should not ask password, if I am using pem key. Also I didnt put any passphrase to pem file, also checked no changes made to ssh config file, As i was able to login using keys previosly. How do I fix it ?

Comment: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@x.x.x.x's password:

Comment: This is debug output while connecting ec2 machine.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.